# google-api-core 1.1.2 has requirement setuptools>=34.0.0

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform

*google-api-core 1.1.2 has requirement setuptools>=34.0.0, but you'll have setuptools 33.1.1 which is incompatible.*

When I tried to install a python package, 'ANUGA' in Google cloud vCPU system, I got a the above message.
Can anyone please reply why? and it's solution.
Thank you

Comment: Hello, has the issue been fixed by applying the solution provided in the answer? If it worked, please consider to accept the answer.

Answer (score 4):

There is a python package called [setup tools](https://pypi.org/project/setuptools/) which allows you to *'Easily download, build, install, upgrade, and uninstall Python packages'*. I can't tell if all packages use this when installing but the Google cloud packages seem to (I had the same problem with the Google Big Query package)

The solution is to upgrade your setuptools package

I used:

```
conda update setuptools
```

If you don't use anaconda then try:

```
pip install setuptools --upgrade
```

PS run this code in the command line, not inside your python code.